# Hidden elements Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium

I wanna know how to find a input what its hidden `type="hidden"` with SeleniumIde, heres the code of the input

```
    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e4s2" id="execution">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**storeVisible ( locator, variableName )**

Determines if the specified element is visible. An element can be rendered invisible by setting the CSS "visibility" property to "hidden", "type" property to "hidden" or the "display" property to "none", either for the element itself or one if its ancestors. This method will fail if the element is not present.

**Arguments:**

```
 •   locator - an element locator   
 •   variableName - the name of a variable
        in which the result is to be stored.
```

**Returns:**
true if the specified element is visible, false otherwise

Related Assertions, automatically generated:

```
•   assertVisible ( locator )
•   assertNotVisible ( locator )
•   verifyVisible (locator )
•   verifyNotVisible ( locator )
•   waitForVisible ( locator )
•   waitForNotVisible ( locator )
```

**You can use**

```
verifyVisible(css=input[name="execution"])
```

Comment: Thanks bro, im a beginner of selenium so verifyVisible(css=input[name="execution"]) i put this in a execute script command field?

Comment: @P4R0DY  you can check how you can use verifyVisible here http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/06/selenium-verifyvisible-and.html?m=1

Comment: @P4R0DY Target would be “css=#execution”